# How can I create a Visual Studio Setup Project MSI that can be installed unattended via AD Group Policy?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, group-policy

if i want to install a MSI, created by Visual Studio 2005, via Active Directory Group Policy:

What requirements must be met by the Setup Project?
How can I specify the installation path? Is this a part of the Group Policy setting? Or do I have to create a special "silent install" version of the MSI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that it is possible to specify the installation path with a custom property called "TARGETDIR". The unattended installation can be tested with:

```
setup.msi /passive TARGETDIR="C:\whatever"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a command MSIExec that installs MSI installers automatically.  This command is what you would use with the Policy.  Any MSI should be compatible with it.

You have a number of options for building installers going with Microsofts default setup projects or something more verbose like Wix.

Comment: Thank you - but how do i specify the target installation folder? Is this a setting of the group policy?

Comment: This is done through the installers as far as I know. You define the folder structure you want in the files to be installed to. I think you can have parameters that will let you specify the folder to install to.